# Column with date data type and Date functions

Tags: mysql, date

I´m practicing Data Types (Dates) and MySQL date functions. So, just for practice, I´m trying to create a table and use both (the previous ones) for “x” column. I also want to do it with other date functions in case if it´s possible to do it.

So,

```
CREATE TABLE testing (
idtesting INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
testingdate date NOT NULL DEFAULT CURDATE()
) ENGINE MyISAM;
```

If I´m not wrong *date data type expects something like*: **YYYY-MM-DD** and *curdate()* returns **YYYY-MM-DD**

But, I´m receiving this ERROR

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURDATE()
) ENGINE MyISAM' at line 3
```

Even when I searched ERROR 1064 (42000), I can´t find a solution.

**Anyone can help me?**

And yes, I want to mix data types and dates functions just to learn. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is very particular about setting default datetime/timestamp columns.  The current date is not permitted -- either a timestamp or datetime (depending on the version of MySQL).

You can read about the defaults in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

(Note:  initializing `datetime` columns is only allowed since 5.6.5.  In earlier versions, only `timestamp` columns could be initialized.)